# bootstrap: equal heights for thumbnails (ideally with flex)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm using bootstrap and I want my boxes to figure out the tallest row and pick that height for all of them. Now I think I should be able to do this with flex but I haven't got it working!

**HTML**:

```
<div class="my-projects">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>

                </h3>
                <p>

                </p>
                <p>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    display: flex
}
.content .thumbnail{
    flex:1;
}
```

This just seems to make the rows really long and thin and massively broken...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
    .thumbnail img:hover {transform: scale(1.1);}
.thumbnail img {transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; width: 100%}
```

You can set the thumbnail size and the images should scale to fit.